# Recreating POSIX open behaviour in PHP

Tags: php, posix, fopen

I'm writing a server in PHP (specifically an SFTP server). The underlying protocol provides a facility with the same semantics as the POSIX [open](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) function (specifically it supports O_READ, O_WRITE, O_RDWR, O_CREAT, O_APPEND, O_EXCL).

However PHP's [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), operating on streams,  uses different semantics ('r', 'r+', 'w'....).

Is there an agreed way of interpreting the semantics of the former using the implementation of the latter?

Comment: If I got what you want (I'm not sure), you want to interpret the PHP language (or kind of one) to a base language (which uses POSIX instead of streams). If I'm right, did you tried to interpret using the Interpreter pattern?

Comment: No, I don't think so: I'm trying to map the semantics of the POSIX open to that of the POSIX fopen (that the implementation will be in PHP is coincidental unless someone can point me to an existing library)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PHP source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.1.3/main/streams/plain_wrapper.c#L66) comes to the rescue about mapping the `fopen()` modes to `open()` combinations of flags.

The other way around, not all combinations of `open()` flags map to an existing `fopen()` mode. Some of the combinations are probably not valid; I don't know how `open()` treats them.

```
/* parse standard "fopen" modes into open() flags */
PHPAPI int php_stream_parse_fopen_modes(const char *mode, int *open_flags)
{
    int flags;

    switch (mode[0]) {
        case 'r':
            flags = 0;
            break;
        case 'w':
            flags = O_TRUNC|O_CREAT;
            break;
        case 'a':
            flags = O_CREAT|O_APPEND;
            break;
        case 'x':
            flags = O_CREAT|O_EXCL;
            break;
        case 'c':
            flags = O_CREAT;
            break;
        default:
            /* unknown mode */
            return FAILURE;
    }

    if (strchr(mode, '+')) {
        flags |= O_RDWR;
    } else if (flags) {
        flags |= O_WRONLY;
    } else {
        flags |= O_RDONLY;
    }

#if defined(O_CLOEXEC)
    if (strchr(mode, 'e')) {
        flags |= O_CLOEXEC;
    }
#endif

#if defined(O_NONBLOCK)
    if (strchr(mode, 'n')) {
        flags |= O_NONBLOCK;
    }
#endif

#if defined(_O_TEXT) && defined(O_BINARY)
    if (strchr(mode, 't')) {
        flags |= _O_TEXT;
    } else {
        flags |= O_BINARY;
    }
#endif

    *open_flags = flags;
    return SUCCESS;
}
```